# "Driver locked" taking up a significant amount of RAM

Tags: windows-10, memory

Lately I realized my laptop is running on 50% memory even at idle. It spikes up from normal to 50-60% on startup, and stays that way onwards.

Therefore I used Rammap to find out what's using up that much of my memory (50% of 16GB), and discovered something called "Driver Locked" is using up close to 5gb or RAM. This didn't help so I ran Windows Assessment Console and had this [results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P30yc.jpg).

Turns out even Windows Assessment Toolkit could't figure out what's eating up my memory. I just got my laptop a week ago, so I hadn't installed that much drivers or software besides Steam and Epic Games. Would appreciate some insight on this.

Comment: What does Windows Admin Tools, Resource Monitor tell you. Run it, maker sure the Memory line is open and let it run for 10 minutes. What process is taking the memory?

Comment: This seems to happen a lot when Hyper-V is enabled and in use on a PC, because for some reason, RAM isn't freed or paged even when no virtual machine is in use. Could be because you chose to pause them? A reboot is usually enough to solve the issue, but if it's not, you should try to disable Hyper-V via msconfig > Services (uncheck everything that has "Hyper-V" in it) and restart your PC.